# Intellij IDEA project build never completing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to build my *Java* project, but the process never completes. The **build** progress spinner just spins forever as if it's stuck in an infinite loop.

My code-base takes 15min to compile via the CI, but after 2 hours IDEA is still busy.

**Why is my IntelliJ IDEA project build not completing?**

I am not sure what additional info might be required to identify the problem; so please tell me and I'll gladly provide.

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 (Community Edition) Build 173.4127.27

Comment: Maybe this question will get a better audience via [IntelliJ Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) or their [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). Though a good place to start would be to examine the logfiles.

Comment: THANK YOU! don't know why I didn't think of looking at IDEA's logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Out Of Memory**

IntelliJ's build log showed an *OutOfMemoryError*.

```
  2018-01-16 14:04:25,367 [   1144]   WARN - channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1368)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.executeOnPooledThread(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.channelRead0(BuildMain.java:231)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.channelRead0(BuildMain.java:209)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-01-16 14:08:09,162 [ 224939]   WARN - channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.channelInactive(BuildMain.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1329)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:744)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I [may](https://dzone.com/articles/outofmemoryerror-unable-create) have hit the thread count limit for JDK 32bit, so I changed to JDK 64bit.

And I increased my build process memory from 64m to 128m.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other reasons for too slow build are slower internet connection and antivirus software installed on the PC.

Normally build dialog should display the files that are currently downloaded. But when the connection is too slow, it does not display these info.

You may also exclude the project folder from scanning on your antivirus software settings.